# No USB connection mode available; PC shows the error: "USB device not recognized"

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, huawei-honor-7

My Huawei Honor 7 is unable to be detected by my computer. Whenever I plug it in, my computer shows the error :

> USB device not recognized.

My phone automatically starts charging but there are no options to connect my phone to the computer.

I've already enabled the USB debugging mode (not sure what it does) but it still just charges whenever I connect it to the computer.

I just want to be able to transfer my files from internal storage across.

Comment: Did you try plugging the device into other USB ports of PC?

Comment: This usually happens when the device drivers are not installed for your specific device on the Windows PC.

Comment: Also if you have a lock screen, make sure to unlock it. For some reason some mobile phones are only in charge mode if lock screen is not unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Device Driver**

If Windows is not able to recognize the device, you may also see in Device Manager that the device shows up as an “Unknown Device”. You can get to Device Manager by clicking on Start and typing in `devmgmt.msc` or by going to Control Panel and clicking on Device Manager.

In that case, you should right-click on **Unknown Device**, click on **Properties**, then the **Driver tab** and then **click Update Driver**.

If this doesn’t work, you can also try to download the driver for your device from the manufacturer’s website. If the USB device is just a flash drive, then it’s probably not a driver issue. However, if you are installing a USB printer, drawing pad, etc, then it might be worth downloading the driver for that specific device.

Answer (score 1):

Download [HiSuite](http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/HiSuite_en/), it will download the specific honor drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend what worked for me and thousand others.

Install [PDANET](http://pdanet.co/bin/PdaNetA4190.exe) on your PC. Then follow the procedure below.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

> The procedure above will install `PDANET` on your PC and Android device which is a Tether application.
>   If you need it, you can keep it, otherwise just uninstall from PC and phone.
>   Your Device will connect to the PC hardware just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Open devices manager and find USB. Now remove any unknown devices. Restart computer. It will find android device. Install huawei usb driver. You can also use Huawei pc suite for windows. You do not need USB driver.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data cable is damaged or broken.. Change it and your problem will be solved! And turn the usb debugging off..

HOPE IT HELPS...